# Object(...) is not a function when adding firebase as argument to a thunk

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, redux-thunk, redux-firestore

It's being a pain to me to configure firebase with redux.

I don't know what's wrong but I feel so stuck. I'm trying to pass `getFirebase` and `getFirestore` as arguments to the `thunk` but I'm having this error:

[image]

I got it working before trying to add the extra argument to the thunk. I'm using the code below:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import rootReducer from './modules'
import {reduxFirestore, getFirestore} from 'redux-firestore'
import {reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase} from 'react-redux-firebase'
import fbConfig from './firebase/config'

export function initializeStore(initialState) {
  const _thunk = thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })

  const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(_thunk)

  const composedEnhancers = compose(
    middlewareEnhancer,
    reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
    reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig)
  )

  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composedEnhancers)

  return store
}
```

Do you have any idea of what could be happening? I'm desperate.

Thank you so much.

Comment: The error is on L14, so start actually debugging that line: what are the things you're pushing into `compose`? (e.g. if you console log them, what does dev tools tell you about them). Also, return to the source: if you just use the plain thunk, and don't capture the apply as a const, does _that part of your code_ now work? (e.g. either the error goes away, or it's now somewhere much later in the code). And [very importantly][(/help/how-to-ask), those details matters, so talk about/show the results of your investigations in your post.

Comment: This is specific to the 'redux-firestore' package. If you are desperate maybe try going through open/old issues posted on their GitHub repo if you don't get any help here.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you mention the version of 'redux-firestore' and 'react-redux-firebase'.

There is a recent migration for react-redux v6:
http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html

The changes you might need to do in your code:

```
- import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase'
+ import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase'

- import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore'
+ import { createFirestoreInstance, reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore'

+ import firebase from "firebase/app";
```

This is used when you have recent version for react-redux-firebase as the API for reactReduxFirebase is removed. 
Also change the composedEnhancers as below:

```
- const composedEnhancers = compose(
-    middlewareEnhancer,
-    reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
-    reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig)
-   )

+  const composedEnhancers = compose(
+     middlewareEnhancer,
+     reduxFirestore(firebase, fbConfig)
+  )
```

Add the react-redux-firebase props

```
+ const rrfProps = {
+   firebase,
+   config: fbConfig,
+   dispatch: store.dispatch, 
+   createFirestoreInstance,
+ }
```

And you need to provide react-redux-firebase props to your app:

```
<ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
        <App />
</ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
```

It should work fine. You can add rrfConfig as mentioned in the link given above, in case if it still doesn't works.