# Object(...) is not a function on index.js when use firestore it give me error

Tags: react-redux-firebase

14 | const store = createStore(
15 |   rootReducer,
16 |   compose(

> 17 |    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
> 18 |    reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
> 19 |    reactReduxFirestore(fbConfig)
> 20 |   )[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw6Aw.png)

Comment: Hi, Muhammad. These sorts of errors can be tricky at first.  You've included a nice screenshot which shows that the error is on line 16. That's the place to start investigating. You can use the browser Developer Tools (F12), to debug into the JavaScript by adding a breakpoint on that line or by adding a ```debugger``` statement.  You could then step into (F11) the various functions on that line to try to see what's happening.  Also, try searching on stackoverflow for "Object(...) is not a function".  There are several posts. Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59010651/1617161

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot call reactReduxFirebase() - TypeError: Object is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66536513/cannot-call-reactreduxfirebase-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function)